# How to set Month In Highchart same to database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, highcharts

I want create report visitor using highchart, but i have a problem
when i show data, this month in highchart not same in **month** in database

you can see my screenshot

- Screenshot : "**Highchart**".
  [image]
- Screenshot : "**Database**"

[image]

you can see field in "**month_visitor**"  this values is

05-2015 (May 2015) and 06-2015 (Juny 2015)
my question how set highchart month same in database ??

- **This is my script**

http://pastebin.com/N0LXyZiW

Help me thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/spline-symbols/ with 12 column names

```
categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

and 12 points of data

```
data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
            y: 26.5,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png)'
            }
        }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
```

if you remove data the chart adjusts to the side. Highcharts assumes that for your axis' you enter you also give valid data. So to fix your highchart either enter 0 for months without any visitors or remove those months you don't want to see.

Comment: depperm, i confused..
can you give me example to my data in screenshot ??

Comment: Here is a fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/bumLsfkh/ these data points are from june, july, and august, but because I specify that my highchart starts with jan, feb,... and I don't specify what data values go there all the data is shifted to jan, the first axis label

Comment: i still confused when i application in php

Answer (score 0):

You need to match your value returned from the database to the array index of your categories.

So, if the month is June, your x value for your data needs to be 5 - the index of June in your categories array.

I would not go about this by having a SQL query in the middle of your chart code - there should be a class and/or function set up to retrieve and process your data before hand - but either way, in your loop as you pull the data to process you'll need to assign both an x and a y value - x for the category index, y for the data value.

**ie, in your PHP, you could do this, assuming you have all 12 months in your categories, by returning the month number -1 as your x value for each data** point.

Alternatively, you can use a `datetime` x axis type, and set the x value as a time stamp instead.

Example using categories:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/6s75mka5/

Reference for `datetime` axis type:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.type